# Printing out a .txt file

Tags: java, arrays

I have a quick question I have a program I am writing in java, it takes a .txt file reads what is inside it(this case it being a bunch of numbers) the program stores it in an array, then it sorts it from least to greatest it also finds the average as well as it tells me how many numbers in the array are bigger than the average. I have managed to do all of that but what I am having trouble with is now I want the program to print out another .txt file but this time with the results of my program. I want it to print out the sorted array the average the number of how many elements are in the array as well as the number of numbers bigger than the average. here is my code that i have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;


class numberSorter{


   public static void main (String[]args)throws Exception{
   //calling the .txt file
      java.io.File file= new java.io.File("numTestData.txt");
      java.io.File file2=new java.io.File("dataOut.txt");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

      //getting the numbers from the file   
      int num=input.nextInt();
      //starting variables
      int ct=0;
      int bigger=0;
      double average;
      double track=0;
      double[]numberArray=new double[num];
     //filling in the rest of the numbers in the array
      for(int i =0; i < numberArray.length; i++){

         numberArray[i] = input.nextInt();
      }
       input.close();  

      //calling the sort method to sort the array
      sort(numberArray);
      //tracking how many elements are in the array
      for(int i=0;i<numberArray.length;i++){

         track+=numberArray[i];

      }
      //finding the average of the sorted array
      average=track/numberArray.length;
      //looking through the array to find which number is bigger than the average
      for(int i=0;i<numberArray.length;i++)
      {
         if(numberArray[i]>average)
            bigger++;
      }
      //checking to see of the .txt file exists
      if(file2.exists()){
            System.out.println("file exists");
            System.exit(0);
         }
         //creating a file
         try(
         java.io.PrintWriter output=new java.io.PrintWriter(file2);
         ){
         //printing out to the .txt file 
         output.println("Number of slots:");
         output.println(numberArray.length);
         output.println("sorted:");
          for(int i =0; i < numberArray.length; i++){

            output.println(numberArray[i]);

         }

         output.println("Average:");
         output.println(average);
         output.println("number of above average values: ");
         output.println(bigger);
        }

   }



   //sort method
   public static void sort(double[]arrange)
   {
      //looking for the smallest number
      for(int i=0;i<arrange.length-1;i++){
         double currentMin=arrange[i];
         int currentMinIndex=i;
         //checking to see if the current number is smaller or bigger
         for(int j=i+1;j<arrange.length;j++){
            if(currentMin>arrange[j]){
               currentMin=arrange[j];
               currentMinIndex=j;
            }
         }
         //will arrange the numbers if current number is not smaller
         if(currentMinIndex!=i){
            arrange[currentMinIndex]=arrange[i];
            arrange[i]=currentMin;
         }
      }

   }
}
```

Now my question is i keep getting this error, everything complies but when I try to run it i come across this:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java numberSorter

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at numberSorter.main(numberSorter.java:26)

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Ive tried to mees around with the code but I still keep getting this any help please? I am still learning java

Comment: Your program expects a file which contains an integer which represents the number of elements in the file. It seems that there are less integer elements in the file than the value of the first integer

Comment: which line is numberSorter.java:26

Comment: Thrown by the nextElement method of an Enumeration to indicate that there are no more elements in the enumeration.

Comment: If you gave us the content of your file we wouldn't have to guess, but here is my guess: The first line of your file has an int that tells how many lines exist in the file. That's why you actually get it before the cycle and use it to initialize the array, the rest of the numbers that you are using are doubles. So, in line 36 you need to use`numberArray[i] = input.nextDouble();`instead.

Comment: @lootu sorry the .txt file i am reading from is: 11
12345
23456
123
4567
123456
7654
999
3453
997733
43
654321

Comment: edit the answer, don't post it here!

Comment: What was the answer? Perhaps you should thank the guy who put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of errors related to a not matching int in the first line, i would recommend not using this first int counting the numbers, you want to parse.
So your input file would be:

```
12345 23456 123 4567 123456 7654 999 3453 997733 43 654321
```

You could use an ArrayList instead of an array and then go through the file with input.hasNext().

I updated the parts in your code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberSorter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // calling the .txt file
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("numTestData.txt");
        java.io.File file2 = new java.io.File("dataOut.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        int bigger = 0;
        double average;
        double track = 0;
        ArrayList<Double> numberArray = new ArrayList<Double>();
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            numberArray.add(input.nextDouble());
        }
        input.close();

        // calling the sort method to sort the array
        sort(numberArray);
        // tracking how many elements are in the array
        for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.size(); i++) {
            track += numberArray.get(i);
        }
        // finding the average of the sorted array
        average = track / numberArray.size();
        // looking through the array to find which number is bigger than the
        // average
        for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.size(); i++) {
            if (numberArray.get(i) > average)
                bigger++;
        }
        // checking to see of the .txt file exists
        if (file2.exists()) {
            System.out.println("file exists");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        // creating a file
        try (java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file2);) {
            // printing out to the .txt file
            output.println("Number of slots:");
            output.println(numberArray.size());
            output.println("sorted:");
            for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.size(); i++) {
                output.println(numberArray.get(i));
            }

            output.println("Average:");
            output.println(average);
            output.println("number of above average values: ");
            output.println(bigger);
        }
    }

    // sort method
    public static void sort(ArrayList<Double> arrange) {
        // looking for the smallest number
        for (int i = 0; i < arrange.size() - 1; i++) {
            double currentMin = arrange.get(i);
            int currentMinIndex = i;
            // checking to see if the current number is smaller or bigger
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arrange.size(); j++) {
                if (currentMin > arrange.get(j)) {
                    currentMin = arrange.get(j);
                    currentMinIndex = j;
                }
            }
            // will arrange the numbers if current number is not smaller
            if (currentMinIndex != i) {
                arrange.set(currentMinIndex, arrange.get(i));
                arrange.set(i,currentMin);
            }
        }
    }
}
```